# C# Merge Join DataTables (using unique id) Loaded by CSV Parser

Tags: c#, csv, join, merge, datatable

I am trying to merge and join two imported CSV files into one single DataTable. C# is new to me but I have done similar in PS and KSH many times before.

The data loads fine and is output to console as ok as two seperate tables, but i can't figure out how to join the results of each ShowTable() using Primary Keys (wID,UserID) as the join condition.

I tried to `return Table_SalesUserData; and return Table_WifiUserData;` that gives  `[ 'Form1.CreateTableWifi()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression ]` errors.

I also tried to use : `DataSet setSalesWifi = new DataSet();` But in the `Button1_Click()` it throws `[  System.ArgumentNullException: ''column' argument cannot be null. Parameter name: column' ]` error.

Which I assume is because the .Columns for each is out of scope.

The tables are created like below.  They are loaded by GenericParser (code work fine and is quite long so haven't posted) these are `InsertTableWifi(string srcFilePathWifi)` and `InsertTableSales(string srcFilePathSales)`.

I think I'm ok to output the merged data when it works, just can't figure out how to join them into either a new DataTable or DataSet.

Is there a simple way to merge the data with what i have?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using GenericParsing;

namespace GenericParserv1._1._6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        DataTable Table_SalesUserData = new DataTable("SalesUserData ");
        DataTable Table_WifiUserData = new DataTable("WifiUserData ");
        DataSet setSalesWifi = new DataSet();

    public void CreateTableSales()
        {
            DataColumn[] colsSales ={
                      new DataColumn("UserID",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("Alias",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("UserType",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("AccountStatus",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("ChgPasswdNxtLogin",typeof(String)),
                  };
            Table_SalesUserData.Columns.AddRange(colsSales);
            Table_SalesUserData.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Table_SalesUserData.Columns["UserID"] };
            setSalesWifi.Tables.Add(Table_SalesUserData);
            //return Table_SalesUserData ;
        }

        public void CreateTableWifi()
        {

            DataColumn[] colsWifi ={
                      new DataColumn("wID",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("username",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("fname",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("lastname",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("email",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("empid",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("lastlogintime",typeof(String))
                  };

            Table_WifiUserData.Columns.AddRange(colsWifi);
            Table_WifiUserData.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Table_WifiUserData.Columns["wID"] };
            setSalesWifi.Tables.Add(Table_WifiUserData);
            //return Table_WifiUserData ;
        }

        public void CreateTableReport()
        {

            DataColumn[] colsMerge ={
                      new DataColumn("wID",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("username",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("fname",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("lastname",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("email",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("empid",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("lastlogintime",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("UserID",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("Alias",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("UserType",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("AccountStatus",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("ChgPasswdNxtLogin",typeof(String)),
                  };

            Table_MergeUserData.Columns.AddRange(colsMerge);
            Table_MergeUserData.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Table_MergeUserData.Columns["wID"] };
        }

        private static void ShowTable(DataTable table)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,-14}", col.ColumnName);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
                        Console.Write("{0,-14:d}", row[col]);
                    else if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(Decimal)))
                        Console.Write("{0,-14:C}", row[col]);
                    else
                        Console.Write("{0,-14}", row[col]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

      private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string srcFilePathWifi = @"c:\WifiUserData.csv";
            string srcFilePathSales = @"c:\SalesUserData.csv";

            CreateTableSales();
            InsertTableSales(srcFilePathSales);

            CreateTableWifi();
            InsertTableWifi(srcFilePathWifi);

            ShowTable(Table_WifiUserData);
            ShowTable(Table_SalesUserData);

            // Set the relations between the tables and create the related constraint.
            setSalesWifi.Relations.Add("Table_WifiUserData", Table_SalesUserData.Columns["wID"], Table_SalesUserData.Columns["UserID"], true);

        }

    }
}
```

WifiUserData.csv:

```
wID           username      fname         lastname      email         empid         lastlogintime 
msmith        marysmith     mary          smith         marysmith@company.com10001         24/01/2019 14:00
jbloggs       joebloggs     joe           bloggs        joebloggs@company.com10002         10/01/2019 9:00
pgolightly    petergolightlypeter         golightly     petergolightly@company.com10003         20/01/2019 17:00
rrabbit       rogerrabbit   roger         rabbit        rogerrabbit@company.com10004         1/02/2019 14:00
```

SalesUserData.csv:

```
UserID        Alias         UserType      AccountStatus ChgPasswdNxtLogin
msmith        mary smith    Manager       No            No            
jbloggs       joe bloggs    Standard      No            No            
pgolightly    peter golightlyJunior        No            No            
rrabbit       roger rabbit  Standard      No            No
```

What I am aiming for:

```
UserID  Alias   UserType    AccountStatus   ChgPasswdNxtLogin   username    fname   lastname    email   empid   lastlogintime
msmith  mary smith  Manager No  No  marysmith   mary    smith   marysmith@company.com 10001 24/01/2019 14:00
jbloggs joe bloggs  Standard    No  No  joebloggs   joe bloggs  joebloggs@company.com 10002 10/01/2019 9:00
pgolightly  peter golightly Junior  No  No  petergolightly  peter   golightly   petergolightly@company.com 10003    20/01/2019 17:00
rrabbit roger rabbit    Standard    No  No  rogerrabbit roger   rabbit  rogerrabbit@company.com 10004   1/02/2019 14:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  I put one column in the merged table and left the rest to you. :

```
       public void CreateTableReport()
        {

            DataColumn[] colsMerge ={
                      new DataColumn("wID",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("username",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("fname",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("lastname",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("email",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("empid",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("lastlogintime",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("UserID",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("Alias",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("UserType",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("AccountStatus",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("ChgPasswdNxtLogin",typeof(String)),
                  };

            Table_MergeUserData.Columns.AddRange(colsMerge);

            var mergedData = (from s in Table_SalesUserData.AsEnumerable()
                              join w in Table_WifiUserData.AsEnumerable() on s.Field<string>("UserID") equals w.Field<string>("wID")
                              select new { sales = s, wifi = w }).ToList();

            foreach (var data in mergedData)
            {
                Table_MergeUserData.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    data.sales.Field<string>("wID")
                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: #jdweng ... you my friend, and I do say so not lightly, as you will see below, I use the term with the highest regard. It worked perfectly.  I have extended it to produce the whole table as a merge of both in exactly the format required. TBH, in 20+ years of coding scripts i remember only asking online like this 7x times. So when help comes when i do, I greatly respect what was passed on and the time taken by selfless people to help random strangers. ```slow bow and smile to you```. thank you. Let me post the final script below as this field is very short on what I can say. :)))))

Comment: PS.  I tried to "Up Vote" you #jdweng but:

```


Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
```

Comment: You may want to look at the linq samples at msdn which has the join method : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: PPS... anyone else with god status please upvote #jdweng on his replay at it works perfectly... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@jdweng... thanks again :) I had a look back at my browser history and it seems I have looked at over 173 pages in the last week, regarding the issue before I came here, so I am happy that i didnt unintentionally waste any ones time by asking!  Ok, so here's the final (FULL) result and code based on using #jdweng's reply.

I will post the whole code as I really vehemently dislike with a passion when people get a fix and don't post what they came up with, hence, after 173 pages and no joy!. Maybe it will help some else with the same problem in perpituity.

1) The final Result (console.writeline) looks like this:

```
//------- MergeUserData--------------//
wID           username      fname         lastname      email         empid         lastlogintime UserID        Alias         UserType      AccountStatus ChgPasswdNxtLogin
msmith        marysmith     mary          smith         marysmith@company.com10001         24/01/2019 14:00msmith        mary smith    Manager       No            No            
jbloggs       joebloggs     joe           bloggs        joebloggs@company.com10002         10/01/2019 9:00jbloggs       joe bloggs    Standard      No            No            
pgolightly    petergolightlypeter         golightly     petergolightly@company.com10003         20/01/2019 17:00pgolightly    peter golightlyJunior        No            No            
rrabbit       rogerrabbit   roger         rabbit        rogerrabbit@company.com10004         1/02/2019 14:00rrabbit       roger rabbit  Standard      No            No
```

2) the final `CreateTableReport()` looks like this (UAT tested passed):

```
 public void CreateTableReport()
        {

            DataColumn[] colsMerge ={
                      new DataColumn("wID",typeof(String)),      //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("username",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("fname",typeof(String)),    //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("lastname",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("email",typeof(String)),    //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("empid",typeof(String)),    //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("lastlogintime",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("UserID",typeof(String)),   //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("Alias",typeof(String)),    //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("UserType",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("AccountStatus",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("ChgPasswdNxtLogin",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                  };

            Table_MergeUserData.Columns.AddRange(colsMerge);

            var mergedData = (from s in Table_SalesUserData.AsEnumerable()
                              join w in Table_WifiUserData.AsEnumerable() on s.Field<string>("UserID") equals w.Field<string>("wID")
                              select new { sales = s, wifi = w }).ToList();

            foreach (var data in mergedData)
            {
                Table_MergeUserData.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    data.sales.Field<string>("UserID"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("username"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("fname"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("lastname"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("email"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("empid"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("lastlogintime"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("UserID"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("Alias"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("UserType"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("AccountStatus"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("ChgPasswdNxtLogin")
                });

            }
```

3) And now for the whole enchelade, or however that is spelled.

The whole Form1.csv, using all the same CSV files originally added, and......the CSV Parser code to import both CSV files in the first place. Hope it helps someone else in the future. This was all done in Visual Studio 2019 Community, with all the libraries etc in the "using" section.

The "Form1" is a basic form, with one button "Show Table". I got the basic jist of this from the great/simple tutorial from msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/tutorial-1-create-a-picture-viewer?view=vs-2019 .

If you are *new* to Visual Studio like i am, this is really great. In 1x week I have learnt how to do that tutorial, then regress my linux and Powershell scripts to do LDAP searches, merge data, import XLS workbooks, export to CSV, re-import CSV files and now with help from the Stack overflow community (jdwen) join dataTables and create something useful. Happiness has no bounds ! :)))

Ok enough from me here it all is:

```
//========================================//
//--- Useful Pages to check out ----------//
//========================================//
//--- https://immortalcoder.blogspot.com/2013/12/convert-csv-file-to-datatable-in-c.html
//--- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-DataTable-7abb4914
//--- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader
//--- https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable
//--- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8#examples


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using GenericParsing;


namespace GenericParserv1._1._6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        DataTable Table_SalesUserData = new DataTable("SalesUserData");
        DataTable Table_WifiUserData = new DataTable("WifiUserData");
        DataTable Table_MergeUserData = new DataTable("MergeUserData");
        DataSet   setSalesWifi = new DataSet();


        private static void ShowTable(DataTable table)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("//------- " + table + "--------------//");

            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,-14}", col.ColumnName);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
                        Console.Write("{0,-14:d}", row[col]);
                    else if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(Decimal)))
                        Console.Write("{0,-14:C}", row[col]);
                    else
                        Console.Write("{0,-14}", row[col]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        public void CreateTableSales()
        {
            DataColumn[] colsSales ={
                      new DataColumn("UserID",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("Alias",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("UserType",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("AccountStatus",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("ChgPasswdNxtLogin",typeof(String)),
                  };
            Table_SalesUserData.Columns.AddRange(colsSales);
            Table_SalesUserData.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Table_SalesUserData.Columns["UserID"] };
            setSalesWifi.Tables.Add(Table_SalesUserData);

        }

        public void InsertTableSales(string srcFilePathSales)
        {
            string Sales_UserID,
            Sales_Alias,
            Sales_UserType,
            Sales_AccountStatus,
            Sales_ChgPasswdNxtLogin
            ;

            using (GenericParser parser = new GenericParser())
            {
                parser.SetDataSource(srcFilePathSales);

                parser.ColumnDelimiter = ','; //---- For TAB DELIM USE: parser.ColumnDelimiter = "\t".ToCharArray();
                parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
                parser.SkipStartingDataRows = 0;
                parser.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
                parser.MaxRows = 500;
                parser.TextQualifier = null;

                while (parser.Read())
                {

                    Sales_UserID = parser["UserID"];
                    Sales_Alias = parser["Alias"];
                    Sales_UserType = parser["UserType"];
                    Sales_AccountStatus = parser["AccountStatus"];
                    Sales_ChgPasswdNxtLogin = parser["ChgPasswdNxtLogin"];


                    Object[] rows = {


                        new Object[]{
                                    Sales_UserID
                                    ,Sales_Alias
                                    ,Sales_UserType
                                    ,Sales_AccountStatus
                                    ,Sales_ChgPasswdNxtLogin
                        }
                     };

                    foreach (Object[] row in rows)
                    {
                        Table_SalesUserData.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        public void CreateTableWifi()
        {

            DataColumn[] colsWifi ={
                      new DataColumn("wID",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("username",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("fname",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("lastname",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("email",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("empid",typeof(String)),
                      new DataColumn("lastlogintime",typeof(String))
                  };

            Table_WifiUserData.Columns.AddRange(colsWifi);
            Table_WifiUserData.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Table_WifiUserData.Columns["wID"] };
            setSalesWifi.Tables.Add(Table_WifiUserData);

        }

        public void InsertTableWifi(string srcFilePathWifi)
        {

            string Wifi_wID, Wifi_username, Wifi_fname, Wifi_lastname, Wifi_email, Wifi_empid, Wifi_lastlogintime;

            using (GenericParser parser = new GenericParser())
            {
                parser.SetDataSource(srcFilePathWifi);

                parser.ColumnDelimiter = ','; //---- For TAB DELIM USE: parser.ColumnDelimiter = "\t".ToCharArray();
                parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
                parser.SkipStartingDataRows = 0;
                parser.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
                parser.MaxRows = 500;
                parser.TextQualifier = null;

                while (parser.Read())
                {

                    Wifi_wID = parser["wID"];
                    Wifi_username = parser["username"];
                    Wifi_fname = parser["fname"];
                    Wifi_lastname = parser["lastname"];
                    Wifi_email = parser["email"];
                    Wifi_empid = parser["empid"];
                    Wifi_lastlogintime = parser["lastlogintime"];

                    Object[] rows = {


                        new Object[]{
                                    Wifi_wID
                                    ,Wifi_username
                                    ,Wifi_fname
                                    ,Wifi_lastname
                                    ,Wifi_email
                                    ,Wifi_empid
                                    ,Wifi_lastlogintime
                        }
                     };

                    foreach (Object[] row in rows)
                    {
                        Table_WifiUserData.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

         public void CreateTableReport()
        {

            DataColumn[] colsMerge ={
                      new DataColumn("wID",typeof(String)),      //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("username",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("fname",typeof(String)),    //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("lastname",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("email",typeof(String)),    //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("empid",typeof(String)),    //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("lastlogintime",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: wifi
                      new DataColumn("UserID",typeof(String)),   //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("Alias",typeof(String)),    //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("UserType",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("AccountStatus",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                      new DataColumn("ChgPasswdNxtLogin",typeof(String)), //--- Below foreach from table: sales
                  };

            Table_MergeUserData.Columns.AddRange(colsMerge);

            var mergedData = (from s in Table_SalesUserData.AsEnumerable()
                              join w in Table_WifiUserData.AsEnumerable() on s.Field<string>("UserID") equals w.Field<string>("wID")
                              select new { sales = s, wifi = w }).ToList();

            foreach (var data in mergedData)
            {
                Table_MergeUserData.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    data.sales.Field<string>("UserID"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("username"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("fname"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("lastname"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("email"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("empid"),
                    data.wifi.Field<string>("lastlogintime"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("UserID"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("Alias"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("UserType"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("AccountStatus"),
                    data.sales.Field<string>("ChgPasswdNxtLogin")
                });

            }

        }


        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string srcFilePathWifi = @"C:\WifiUserData.csv";
            string srcFilePathSales = @"C:\SalesUserData.csv";

            CreateTableSales();
            InsertTableSales(srcFilePathSales);

            CreateTableWifi();
            InsertTableWifi(srcFilePathWifi);

            ShowTable(Table_WifiUserData);
            ShowTable(Table_SalesUserData);

            CreateTableReport();
            ShowTable(Table_MergeUserData);

        }
    }
}
```